# jQuery replacing $ sign adds $ signs to the end of the string

Tags: jquery

So, my overall project is to get emails from an AJAX call going through PHP's imap.  That's complete.  I have all emails and they are separated.

I am now going through each email and "highlighting" certain words by replacing the word with `<b>word</b>`.  This works, mostly.  I would like to be able to do this with a dollar sign, but it is causing a very strange problem.

Let's assume I have an email that says:

```
It will cost $500.  How's thursday sound?
```

I have an array that is full of words I'd like to "highlight":

```
var keywords = [
    ....
    "Wednesday",
    "wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "thursday",
    "Friday",
    "friday",
    ....
    ":",
    "$",
    "%",
    ....
]
```

(the ellipsis are showing that there are many keywords before and after what you see there).

I'm using this to replace each word and make it bold:

```
function highlightImportant(that) {
    that.find('.email-container').each(function(){
        var full_text = $(this).text();
        $.each(keywords, function(i) {
            full_text = full_text.replace(new RegExp(keywords[i],"gi"), "<b>"+keywords[i]+"</b>");
        });
       $(this).html(full_text);
    });
}
```

This works on all of the words and characters, but the dollar sign is acting very strange.  The problem is, for some reason when this runs, it adds a dollar sign to the end of the email (string) every time, then makes only that dollar sign bold....  So for every email, it adds another dollar sign to the end:

```
It will cost $<b>5</b><b>0</b><b>0</b>.  How's <b>thursday</b> sound?<b>$</b>
```

Notice the dollar sign at the beginning of `$500` is not bolded, but a dollar sign is added the end of the string?

Take a look at this fiddle to see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/2L3vhtwh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new RegExp("\\"+keywords[i],"gi")` 
to handle special characters. `$` is a special character.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/2L3vhtwh/3/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - Will accept when the time limit is up.  I thought it had to do with special characters, but I couldn't figure out how to escape them

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to extend your keywords to contain regular expressions, you'll need to add the escape to the items in your array instead of directly in the RegExp. For what you currently have, @void is spot on, but if you want to make more complex searches, like sentences that start with "Who", "What", "Where", "Why" or "When" (e.g. trying to determine if the sentence being parsed is a question) then something like "^Wh(o|at|ere|y|en)" would be over-escaped because the carat means something special to you.

Just a heads up for future design considerations.

Also - based on your code, "gi" means global and case insensitive. Having "Friday" and "friday" is causing more loops than necessary, slowing down the performance of your page.

Comment: Great information - Thank you so much, +1 for the info.  I am totally incompetent when it comes to regex and need to learn more.